# Facebook Messenger incompatibility with Nexus 7

Tags: nexus-7, facebook-messenger

Is it possible to install [Facebook Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS5mYWNlYm9vay5vcmNhIl0.) on a Nexus 7?

I just tried but it says that the device isn't compatible without explaining to me why. It is hard for me to think of any hardware limitation that would prevent me from using that application.

Comment: I don't know how, but after having updated the operating system and some other applications I was able to install the Facebook Messenger version present on the Play Store

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the incompatibility came only on the current version. You may install and use an older version or wait till it becomes available to your device.

In [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1897046) there is a link to an older apk version that should work.